# Removing option from similar droplists, but keeping its own, in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jQuery. I have a droplist that is selected retrieved from a function. The list consists of 10 items. I have 10 droplists in my layout. Everytime one of the options are selected from one of the 10 droplists, I want that option removed from all other droplists. The following code is what I've come up with so far, but it removes the selected option from the droplist that was first to select one option.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    $removePlayerID = $(this).attr('value');
    $("#Teamone option[value=" + $removePlayerID + "]").remove();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfX7n/

So when one option is selected, the other droplists don't have that option anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand... Can you put up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 var $allSelects = $('select');

 $allSelects.change(function(){
    $allSelects.not(this).find('option[value='+ $(this).val()+']').remove();    
});
```

Also remember, once options are gone from a select, they are gone(unless you do some other stuff i mean). So if you change the same select again, the previously removed options in the other selects will not reappear.

Comment: Works for the droplists, but I do have another droplist on the same page, which values randomly dissapears.

Comment: add a specific class to all the droplists that you want to participate in this behaviour. then change var $allSelects = $('select.someclassname')

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $removePlayerID = $(this).attr('value');
        $('select').not( $(this) ).find('option[value=' + $removePlayerID + ']').remove();
    });
});​
```

Also on http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/pkgEA/

**But a bigger issue**:  You need to make sure that there are UNIQUE IDs.  TeamTwo and TeamOne are repeated IDs for each select element.  IDs are meant to be unique.

Comment: try changing the same dropdown multiple times.  it keeps removing available options

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/sidou/qpWuc/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var clone = $('option:selected',this);
    $('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
    $(this).append(clone);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pfX7n/1/)**.